# LDA topics number - determining the 'fit' level with current number of topics

Tags: scikit-learn, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a more theoretical question about LDA (Latent Dirichet Allocation).

When doing LDA we provide number of topics ourselves. As far as I understand it tries to build topic-word-document distributions to minimize perplexity (which is why we are doing it in iterative manner).

So the question - can we fit the LDA several times with different number of topics, check the perplexity of each result and choose the number of topics which yielded minimal perplexity? Or am I misunderstanding the perplexity meaning and the algorithm itself - so the perplexity is actually not a 'fit measure' for LDA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact this is the cross validation method of finding the number of topics. But note that you should minimize the perplexity of a held-out dataset to avoid overfitting.

It's worth noting that a [non-parametric extension of LDA](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf) can derive the number of topics from the data without cross validation. Implementations exist at [David Blei's lab github](https://github.com/Blei-Lab), but at the time of this writing I haven't see HDP LDA implemented in any mainstream, open-source ML libraries.

Caveat: Hierarchal LDA is different. It finds a hierarchy of topics, whereas hierarchal Dirichlet processes let you fit a potentially infinite number of flat topics. (The dual use of "hierarchy" can be confusing.)

Comment: Thank you! Any advice which library has good H-LDA implementation? I do know sklearn has nothing like it, but I am not sure which one has a good implementation

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen an implementation in any of the widely used libraries. [David Blei's lab](https://github.com/Blei-Lab) has two implementations, but I haven't used them. Also, keep in mind that H-LDA is different: It finds a hierarchy of topics. Hierarchal Dirichlet processes lets you fit a potentially infinite number of flat topics. (The dual use of "hierarchy" can be confusing.)

Comment: Now I get it. In such case any advice on where I could read a bit more about the CV method you mentioned - just want to understand if there is anything I need to keep in mind and was there any research which demonstrates potential value of performing such topics number optimization based on perplexity?

Comment: Sure, but clarify for me: Are you asking why we use perplexity, or why cross validate to find the number of clusters?

Comment: I understand why, but I am more interested in why perplexity and what are the potential benefits from business standpoint. Right now I just try to play around with number of topics manually until I get a list of topics which seem meaningful to me. But I want try and come up with the more systematic way of doing this instead of just relying on 'gut feeling'

Comment: Well, perplexity is the convention in language modeling and information retrieval (per the LDA and HDP papers). And it's minimized when likelihood is maximized. In other words, the least-heldout-perplexity model should best predict new data. (I couldn't say more about practical benefits without knowing more about the problem; you might want to post this as a separate question.)